# Appending text files in a loop on array only prints 1 letter of first file

Tags: arrays, vba, io

I have a folder `C:\test\` that has multiple `.txt` files which I need to append to one output text file. Using FSO and TextStream I can write the files explicitly with no problem in this manner:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Const Path As String = "C:\test\"

    Dim helloWorld As Object
    Set helloWorld = FSO.CreateTextFile(FileName:=(Path & "helloworld.txt"), OverWrite:=True, Unicode:=False)

    helloWorld.WriteLine FSO.GetFile("C:\test\Product_ID_update.txt").OpenAsTextStream(ForReading).ReadAll
    helloWorld.WriteLine FSO.GetFile("C:\test\RPT-4475.txt").OpenAsTextStream(ForReading).ReadAll

    helloWorld.Close
End Sub
```

It works perfectly, but I have hundreds of files to append so it would be crazy to type them all out, so I wrote some code to put all the file names into an array, then loop over each index to generate the file path. Here is the code:

```
Sub Combine_Text_Files2()

    Dim InputDirPath As String
    InputDirPath = "C:\test\"

    Dim InputFileType As String
    InputFileType = "*.txt"

    Dim OutputDirPath As String
    OutputDirPath = "C:\test\"

    Dim OutputFileName As String
    OutputFileName = "_CombinedOutput.txt"

    Dim InputFileName As String
    InputFileName = Dir$(InputDirPath & InputFileType)

    Dim FileArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0

    Do Until InputFileName = vbNullString
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(0 To i)
        FileArray(i) = InputFileName
        InputFileName = Dir$
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Stream As Object
    Set Stream = FSO.CreateTextFile((OutputDirPath & OutputFileName), OverWrite:=True, Unicode:=False)

    Dim FileNameAndPath As String

    For i = LBound(FileArray) To UBound(FileArray)
        FileNameAndPath = (InputDirPath & FileArray(i))
        Debug.Print ("Processing: " & FileNameAndPath)

        Dim fileToCopy As File
        Set fileToCopy = FSO.GetFile(FileNameAndPath)

        Dim streamToCopy As TextStream
        Set streamToCopy = fileToCopy.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        Dim text As String
        text = streamToCopy.ReadAll

        Stream.WriteLine FSO.GetFile(FileNameAndPath).OpenAsTextStream(ForReading).ReadAll
        Debug.Print ("Appended to " & OutputFileName & ": " & FileNameAndPath)
    Next i

    Stream.Close

End Sub
```

The `FileNameAndPath` value gets updated correctly, and as it goes through the first `Stream.WriteLine` iteration, it appends *only the first letter of the first file* to the output file, then moves on to the next iteration, and on the next `Stream.WriteLine` it fails due to `Invalid procedure call or argument`.

I've been trying to debug this for quite a while but not certain what is causing this. Only thing I can think of that might be causing it is the array, because it's really the only thing that is different AFAIK... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Additional details**

If I comment out the `WriteLine` call it goes through the entire array, printing all file paths to immediate. As you can see I broke down the original one-liner into multiple steps for debugging.

Replicating it is easy:

- Create a `C:\test\` directory
- Create two or more text files and add text content to each of them
- Run the code in the VBE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was not the code, it works fine (though I feel sure could be improved, I'll take it over to Code Review).

The problem was that some of the source files were actually originally Excel documents that became converted to `.txt` and apparently carried over some meta-data that Notepad ignored, but the VBA compiler did not know what to do with trying to put it into a `String`.

Lesson learned, perform a sanity check of your source data.